# h2 embedded database not embedding / Alternatives for embedding database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, eclipse

So I got a comment on another thread to go use h2 for an embedded database inside of my java app. Basically, I need the .jar file to run on another computer without having to go install a sql server, or h2 on their machine. it must be able to run using the jar and it accesses the database automatically, so the db must ship with the jar.

How do I do that? I am trying to use h2.

The app with h2 will work on my machine with the eclipse IDE closed, but as soon as I put the jar file (with a subfolder of the needed libraries, such as the h2) and run it, it does nothing.

So I ran the jar file from the cmd, and it hits me with the error that the table cannot be found. So how do I ship the database as embedded inside the application?

I saw another project that had a microsoft access database file with his files for the app.
Is it possible to have a database file in the root directory of thge application and use that, and then be able to edit it in microsoft access, phpmyadmin or workbench later? Please advise on this as I have no clue how to do this.

Please be aware that I am relatively new to Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'd ship the database configuration to create the database if it can't find it, then on startup run CREATE TABLE and insert SQL scripts to build up the database on startup.  I've done this a lot with Derby so I'll use that as a reference point.

To do this you need to append `;create=true` onto your database url like the one below.

```
<connection-url>jdbc:derby:C:/mydb;create=true;characterEncoding=utf-8</connection-url>
```

This will ensure the database has been created.  As you now know the database has been created, you can build the structure and contents by shipping a .sql file or something similar that will run against it at startup if the tables don't exist.  This gives you added functionality of you can deploy your application really easily each time you ship it as it will be able to check if the tables exist or not at first deployment and create them if needed.

Comment: But then how do I update the database through a program like workbench, phpMyAdmin or something, or must I do that through the h2.jar?

Comment: Is there a way to copy the entire database from the h2.jar ? As I got the database fine, just the tables were missing.

Comment: You can use SQuirrel SQL to interact with the database.  It's a client specifically designed for embedded databases.  If the tables are missing just run the CREATE TABLE sql you need.

Comment: I know I can run the CREATE TABKE sql, but the database already has all the information in, how do I deploy the application with the database already containing all the information?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "the database already has all the information in, how do I deploy the application with the database already containing all the information?"?  This depends on how you intend to install it.  If you have an installer this could be done as part of that process using something like [inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).  Embedded databases sounds like the way to go though unless you want to have to do a database restore each deployment.

Comment: I have a database with a whole bunch of volunteer info (the program is for a charity) and so the software must just be installed, there must be a database already populated with the information when it installs.